# How to get QEMU/RPi emulator to work for first time in Windows

Tags: qemu

On my Windows machine, I have QEMU and RPI emulation working successfully.  I also have the code I grabbed off an SD card from a working Raspberry Pi.

How do I now execute this code within my emulator?  Do I need to create an image file first from the SD card?

Comment: What SIM card? Did you mean SD card?

Comment: Yes, an SD card I pulled from a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What code? If the code is a program it is executable on the Raspberry Pi, and don't forget to make the file executable (`chmod +x filename`) And by the way, fluffy references are going to give you fluffy answers....